# Removing markers from silverlight line or area series

Tags: silverlight, charts

Is it possible to easily remove the data point markers from a line series or area series chart. I am using the Silverlight Toolkit charts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

```
<chartingToolkit:AreaSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChartData}" DependentValuePath="used" IndependentValuePath="date" IsSelectionEnabled="True">
<chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
```